# Show that a subset of a linearly ordered set might not have a least element.

Tags: real-analysis

I am quite confused about the definition of least element.
I know this definition of least element though from Schramm's Real Analysis

***If S is a subset of an ordered set, a least element of S is an element x , if there is one, such that (i) x belongs to S  and (ii) if y belongs to S and y is comparable to x , then x ≤ y***

Also does the least element need to belong to the subset of S or to the subset of S.
Please clarify with an example.

Comment: there is no subset of $S$ involved, $S$ is the subset. And the least element has to be an element of $S$.

Comment: Ok so the well ordering principle says that A linearly ordered set is said to be well-ordered if every nonempty subset of it has a least element. and the well ordering of natural numbers is an axiom. Can you please give an example of a linearly ordered set which doesn't have a least element in its subset always ?

Comment: @Thomas Basically I need an example of a linearly ordered set which is not well ordered. Also what are the advantages of assuming that Natural numbers are well-ordered ?

Comment: look at $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How can Z be not well ordered??

Comment: 'well ordered' is just a term with the definition you cited. $\Bbb Z$ has no least element, hence it does not satisfy that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{z\in \mathbb{Z}| z \text{ is even}\}$. Then $S$ has no least element. If $z_0\in S$ were a least element, then $z_0-2\in S$ is smaller, so you arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Oh Got it. Thanks .